# how should I structure these objects

Tags: java, inheritance, structure

I'm trying to make a system for comics that has releases and copies. What I'm after is a structure where you have on release with certain properties and several copies with the same properties but also unique ones. I was thinking of using inheritance but I want the copies to have a single superclass, release. Also I don't want the copies to contain the release properties, but I want to be able to fetch them from the superclass. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Code aside, is a 'Copy' a specific kind of 'Release'? Just like you might define a`Dog` class as a subclass of `Animal`, because a 'Dog' is a type of 'Animal' and has all of the properties of a generic 'Animal', would you say the same for a 'Copy' and a 'Release'? If not, the approach you're describing is bad form.

Comment: Copy is a specific kind of release, each copy will have some unique properties. But each copy will also have the exact same release and as far as I understand using inheritance will create a release for each copy which is not what I'm looking for. I also wish to be able to access the release properties without storing them in the copy.

Comment: Sounds like `Copy` should contain a property of type `Release` and that inheritance is not what you want here.